# beforeSave not called on associated rows

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, has-many, before-save

I've been having problems trying to get my associated rows to perform the beforeSave function when they are called by the owner object. For this example I have used Asset and AssetVersion as in an Asset hasMany Versions.

My intention is to use beforeSave in the AssetVersion model to find the highest current version number via find then put that into the DB. I can of course not use saveAssociated in the controller and capture the asset_id then call save on an AssetVersion model but that does not feel the right way to do it.  The beforeSave gets called in Asset but not in AssetVersion.

```
class AssetsController extends AppController
{
    public function add()
    {
        if (!$this->request->is('post'))
            return false;

        $md5 = md5(microtime(true));

        $data['Versions'] = array(
            array(
                'md5' => $md5,
            )
        );
        debug($data);

        $this->Asset->create();
        if ($this->Asset->saveAll($data))
        {
            die('boom');
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The asset has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The asset could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}

class Asset extends AppModel
{   
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Versions' => array(
            'className' => 'AssetVersions'
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {   
        if(!isset($this->data['Asset']['created_id']))
            $this->data['Asset']['created_id'] = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');

        $this->data['Asset']['updated_by'] = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
        return parent::beforeSave();
    }

}

class AssetVersion extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Asset'
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        debug('I dont get called at all');
        debug($this->data);
        die();
    }
}
```

Any idea what I have not done right? I have been trying to debug what gets called in CakePHP itself and have so far proved that an event gets dispatched when it's saving the associated data but I don't see my debug in AssetVersion at all.

Comment: This may have been CakePHP 1.3, but I think `beforeSave` isn't triggered on associated models during `saveAll`. Seems wrong, I know. But I vaguely remember a similar problem.

Comment: Just to add to this I have tried saveAssociated too, in both cases it runs through saveMany and then dispatches beforeSave on AppModel and not AssetVersion, this might be an actual bug or intended behaviour as you say